# HP DV7 powers on and off two or three times

Tags: windows-7, windows

HP  DV7 will not power on with just battery or will not power on with just charger connected.But with both connected it will power on and off two or three times. It just started this and I can not get it to power on. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Several possibilities:

Defective AC adapter (Try a new one or one from another HP laptop)

Defective DC socket on the laptop where the power cord connects (Inspect using a flashlight, look for center pin damage)

Defective motherboard. (Requires a qualified technician to know for sure)